# Must a countable disjoint union of closed balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with positive radius be disconnected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

A disjoint union of open balls is of course disconnected. [Here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-mathematical-bulletin/article/spaces-which-cannot-be-written-as-a-countable-disjoint-union-of-closed-subsets/D24FAD263DF49239740F1A548826CA1B) it is proved that a locally compact, connected, Hausdorff space is not a countable disjoint union of compact subsets, so a countable disjoint union of closed balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can't be connected and locally compact (hence cannot be open or closed connected), which rules out the connected sets for $n=1$. But what if we just ask this disjoint union to be connected?

Please forgive me if this question turns out to be trivial. Thank you in advance for any help.

**Edit.** Actually I should have asked about something more general, like

> Is there a connected subset $\mathbb{R}^n$ that can be written as a countable disjoint union of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$? If not, is there a connected subset $\mathbb{R}^n$ that can be written as a countable disjoint union of closed sets in the subspace topology?

And the answer to the second question above is still negative for $n=1$, or for open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (the link requires also local connectedness which is satisfied for open connected sets). However, I will keep the question as it was given the discussion already presented.

**Edit 2.** A connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a countable disjoint union of closed sets has be constructed in the existing answer. I would still be interested in the closed ball case: Must a countable disjoint union of **closed balls** in $\mathbb{R}^n$ not be connected?

Comment: Doesn't the disjoint part already kill it?

Comment: A connected space is defined as a topological space that cannot be represented as the union of 2 or more disjoint non-empty open subsets. So, by definition, the answer is pretty trivially yes.

Comment: @Joseph_Kopp But each closed ball is not necessarily an open subset of the union, as an  infinite union of closed sets is not necessarily closed.

Comment: But they will be open in their subspace topology, which is all that matters.

Comment: @Randall $\{0\}$ is not open in $\{0\}\cup\left\{\dfrac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$, and this can be modified to be an example containing closed segments

Comment: Correct, and those also aren't closed intervals of positive radius.

Comment: You are correct in that there is a good question here.  Your concern is that the balls could converge in a strange way, in the same way we build the topologist's sine curve to make pathology happen.

Comment: @Randall If you like, $[-1,0]$ is not open in $[-1,0]\cup\left[\dfrac{1}{2},1\right]\cup\left[\dfrac{1}{4},\dfrac{1}{3}\right]\cup\cdots$.

Comment: @Randall Yes, in a counterexample every closed ball should be non open, which is quite strong.

Comment: The result follows from Sierpinski's theorem in the case $n=1$.  Any countable disjoint union of closed intervals in $\mathbb R$ is disconnected.  So you can edit your question to assume $n>1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Example of countable family of pairwise disjoint closed sets on a plane whose union is connected

Here is a relatively simple example. The other section has an older, more complicated example in $ℝ^3$.

Let $D = \{d_n : n=0,1,\dots\}$ be a dense subset of unit sphere with $d_n \neq d_m$. For each $n=1,2\dots$ define the line segment
$$
A_n = \{ λd_n : 2^{-n} ≤ λ ≤ 1 \},
$$
and $A_0 = \{ λd_0 : 0 ≤λ≤1 \}$.
Let $\text{Sun} = \bigcup_{n=0}^∞ A_n$. It is a union of closed, pairwise disjoint, connected sets. We show that $\text{Sun}$ is connected. Before proof, here is how $A_0,A_1 \dots, A_5$ might look like.

[image]

*Proof.* Let $U,V$ be open disjoint sets with $\text{Sun} = U \cup V$. Without loss of generality assume that $U$ contains  $0\in A_0$. Since $A_0$ is connected, it must be contained in $U$. It suffices to show that $A_1, A_2, \dots$ are in $U$ as well.

First, note that there is $N$ for which ball $B = B(0, 2^{-N})\cap A$ is contained in $U$. Consequently, for each $k>N$ an endpoint of $A_k$, namely $2^{-k}d_k$, is close enough to the origin to be contained in $B \subset U$. Hence, all $A_k$ with $k>N$ are in $U$ ($A_n$'s are connected).

It remains to show that $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_N$ are also in $U$. Pick $1≤t≤N$. By construction $d_t \in A_t$. Assume that this point sits in $V$. Then there would be a neighborhood of $d_t$ with no points in common with $U$. This is impossible because $U$ contains $\{d_k : k>N \} \subset D$ which is dense in the unit sphere since it's just $D$ with finitely many points thrown out. Hence $d_t$ belongs to $U$, and so $A_t$ is in $U$.

□

*Note*. Via the natural embedding, this will work in higher dimensions.

*Edit.* I have just found a construction of set with the same property in the literature: In the 1922 paper, Anna Mullkin presented perhaps the first example of such set. It's called Mullikin Nautilus and it is constructed by taking an infinite union of such polygonal chains:

[image]

See: [Certain Theorems Relating to Plane Connected Point Sets](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1989040).

## Old example in $ℝ^3$

We construct a family  $\{A_n: n =0,1, \dots\}$ of pairwise disjoint, closed subsets of $ℝ^3$ whose union is connected.

First, let $A_0 =\{(0,t,0): t≤0\}$ be ray. For $n≥1$ set $A_n$ is made of a ray $\{(0,2^{-n},0) : t≤ 0\}$ and a certain polygonal chain. Here is a sketch of the projection of $A_0, A_1, \dots A_5$ to XY plane.

[image]

Important bits:

- Each $A_n$ live on XY plane (the Z-coordinate is zero) except "bridge". Bridges make $A_n$'s pairwise disjoint.
- Each $A_n$ is closed and connected.
- For $n=1,2, \dots$ point $(0,2^{-n},0)$ and $(n,2^{-n},0)$ belong to $A_n$. Fix $n$, then for $t>n$ point of the form $x_{n,t} = (n,2^{-n}+2^{-t},0)$ belongs to $A_t$. Note $$x_{n,t}\stackrel{t→∞}→(n,2^{-n},0)\in A_n.$$ In the picture example with $n=2$.[image]

This is all we need to know to prove that $A = \bigcup_n A_n$ is connected. At the end of the proof, we define $A_n$ for $n≥1$ at the end in detail. I will be glad for a verification!

*Proof*. Say $U,V$ are open (in the subspace topology) disjoint sets with $U\cup V=A$. We will show that one of them is empty. WLOG assume that $U$ contains the origin point $(0,0,0)$. Hence $U$ must contain $A_0$. Also, there must be some $N$ such that for $n≥N$ points $(0,2^{-n},0)$ are in $U$. Becasue each $A_n$ is connected, each $A_n$ with $n≥N$ is in $U$.

When $N=1$ set $U$ contains all $A_n$'s, that is $A\subset U$. So must be $V$ is empty as $U\cap V =∅$. Assume that $N>1$. We show that $U$ contains the remaing $A_{N-1}, A_{N-2}, \dots, A_2, A_1$. Pick any $k \in \{1,2, \dots, N-1\}$ and assume $A_k \subset V$. By construction point $x = (k, 2^{-k}, 0)$ sits in $A_k$. On the other hand, the sequence of points from $U$, namely $(x_{k,t})_{t=N}^{∞} = ((k, 2^{-k}+2^{t}, 0))_{t=N}^{∞}$ where  $x_{k,t}\in A_t \subset U$, conveges to $x\in A_k \subset V$. Hence $V$ will contain almost all points of this sequence. But all terms of the sequence are members of $U$. So  $U$ and $V$ will have infinitely many points in common! A contradiction with $U$ and $V$ being disjoint.

□

---

$A_1$ consist of:

- Ray $\{(2^{-1},t,0): t≤0\}$.
- A "bridge" made of a polygonal chain connecting three points$$(0,2^{-1},0), \quad (0,2^{-1},1), \quad (1,2^{-1},0).$$

For $n≥2$ let $A_n$ be a union of:

- Ray $\{t, (2^{-n} ,0): t≤0\}$.
- Line segment connecting $$(0,2^{-n},0),\quad (1,2^{-1}+2^{-n},0),$$ and for $k=1,2, \dots, n-2$ line segment connecting $$(k,2^{-k}+2^{-n},0),\quad (k+1,2^{-(k+1)}+2^{-n},0).$$
- And a "bridge" made from polygonal chain connecting $$(n-1, 2^{-(n-1)}+2^{-n},0), \quad (n-1, 2^{-(n-1)}+2^{-n},1),\quad (n,2^{-n},0).$$

Comment: Excellent example and demonstration! Just a remark: The negative part of the example $\{(t,0,0):t\le 0\}$ and $\{(t,2^{-n},0):t\le 0\}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$ is not needed. I would simplify the proof as follows: Suppose that the union can be written as $U\cup V$, with $U$ and $V$ open. Each $A_k$ is connected, so it is entirely included in $U$ or in $V$. For any $k\in\mathbb{N}^*$, $A_k\subset U$ means that $A_n\subset U$ for all sufficiently large $n$, since $x_{k,n}\in A_n$ converges to a point in $A_k$ as $n\to\infty$. This implies that every $A_k$ lies in fact in the same open set.